# Query Execution Failed in Reporting Services reports

Tags: ssrs, sql-server

I have some reporting services reports that talk to Analysis Services and at times they fail with the following error:

```
An error occurred during client rendering.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'AccountManagerAccountManager'.
The connection cannot be used while an XmlReader object is open.
```

This occurs sometimes when I change selections in the filter. It also occurs when the machine has been under heavy load and then will consistently error until SSAS is restarted.

The log file contains the following error:

```
processing!ReportServer_0-18!738!04/06/2010-11:01:14:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'AccountManagerAccountManager'., ; Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'AccountManagerAccountManager'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection cannot be used while an XmlReader object is open.
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.CheckConnection()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.ExecuteStatement(String statement, IDictionary connectionProperties, IDictionary commandProperties, IDataParameterCollection parameters, Boolean isMdx)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.IExecuteProvider.ExecuteTabular(CommandBehavior behavior, ICommandContentProvider contentProvider, AdomdPropertyCollection commandProperties, IDataParameterCollection parameters)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.AdoMdCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeDataSet.RunDataSetQuery()
```

Can anyone shed light on this issue?

Comment: I've tried turning off the Use Single Transaction option on the report and so far the issue has not returned.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. I unchecked the "Use single transaction when processing queries" checkbox in the Dataset's Data Source's Properties.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a code question to me. You sure, you didn't find any answers on stackoverflow.com for this ?

For me, it just seems like some XMLReader object is left open...so some service or program which is using it must be closed properly.

Comment: Yeah I thought about posting there but I'm not coding at all here, the error is internal to SSRS so I've been thinking it may be a configuration issue.